# Allow whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, if I was to add something in my input with a space(**test test**)and hit submit, it would show it as **test+test** also if i double hit submit, it shows it **test%2Btest** instead of **test+test**
Need help with those things..

```
<form name="input" action="" method="get">
Search: <input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var form_data = ($(this).serialize());
    window.location.hash = form_data.replace('=','/');
    return false;
});

$(window).on('hashchange', updateVal);

updateVal();

function updateVal() {
   var values = window.location.hash.slice(1).split('/');
   $("[name=" + values[0] + "]").val(decodeURIComponent(values[1]));
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the URL encoding is a problem?

Comment: You can always disable the button after 1 click as well.

Comment: If i was to type test test and hit submit, it will stay as test+test also there's a problem with my url... first time I hit submit - perfect, url goes to test+test. If i was to click submit again(without changing anything) - url changes to test%2Btest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace `+` to space each time you set a value of input:

```
$("[name=" + values[0] + "]").val(decodeURIComponent((values[1] || '').replace(/\+/g, ' ')));
```

Working example you can see here: http://jsbin.com/elewux/2/edit

Comment: What if it's a valid '+' sign in the string? Such as `2+2=4`?